# Every page has "Unknown widgetClass" error in the ToolTwist designer

Tags: tooltwist

I am viewing my web design in the ToolTwist Designer, using the command

```
tooltwist -n designer
```

My navpoints show correctly, but every page shows the error message *"Invalid Widget: Unknown widgetClass:"*. The version of the page is shown as *"shared_"*.

This is different to the Unknown widgetClass error that provides a java class name, that occurs when an extension project jar is missing. In this case there is no class name provided, giving the appearance of an incomplete error message.

What is causing the problem - I know this webdesign can be edited correctly elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when you have a webdesign created with v8.5 and later, but have defined an earlier version in the `tooltwist.js` configuration file.

To correct the problem, update the configuration to use 8.5 or later.

```
"mode" : "docker",
"version" : "8.5.0-SNAPSHOT",
```